# Berryboot, raspbian, docker, SSD, aufs vs overlay2 storage drivers, nnc1: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt, pi 4b

Tags: pi-4, driver, storage, docker, berryboot

My goal is to step up my Raspberry Pi 4B with berryboot loading the OS onto an SSD where I can start running docker to become better familiar with it. Then use pi-hole and pivpn and whatever else might be good for my network. I am running into issues different issues.

Details:

- Raspberry Pi 4B 1.1 (dt)
- 32GB SD card came in canakit for everything -formated fat32
- SSD - 2.5" SATA III 480GB - formated exFat (Not sure if correct but worked)

Very easily set up berryboot and SSD, but I started running into problems when docker came into play. Every time I install docker it is using the aufs storage driver. Docker does not like aufs apparently and wants overlay2 as its storage driver.

I went into `raspi-config` to see if something was there about storage drivers. I found this overlay thing under "advanced". I enabled it with the ability to write to it not only read it because again I am not quite sure what I am doing but I assume I can just reformat any and try again if it fails.

I then tried to reboot and now the `nnc1: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt`. I turned it off and tried turning it back on with the same error and it not actually booting at all.

I will be starting over from scratch now and would very much appreciate any help or just any info about what I am describing. Even if it is only part of my issue and won't solve the entire issue.

If anyone wants to know about the commands I used to install docker.

`curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ |sh`

Sometimes I have to add  `--fix-missing` because it asks me to despite the fact I wouldn't think anything was missing because I have fresh installs.

If any more information is needed I will be quick to add any info needed since I am home all the time now with the Virus out and about. Stay safe everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I found a new way to get docker running on the lastest raspbian OS with raspi 4b. Unfortunately I had to scrap berryboot because the kernel for berryboot isn't compatible with docker I believe so no SSD :(

1. Download Debian Buster
2. Enable SSH file in root of SD card if not running desktop
3. curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
4. sh get-docker.sh
5. sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
6. docker pull portainer/portainer
7. docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --restart always --name portainer portainer/portainer -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Then just go to your browser type in your-IP--address:9000 and you should be at portainer to manage your docker containers. If you run into an issue with passwords there are a couple easy things to do to fix them online or ask.

I was able to get pihole up and running on a container and now am trying to get pivpn with wireguard but I am unsure if that is feasible yet for me being a noob and still struggling. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found [this solution](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/boot-raspberry-pi-from-usb,39782.html) to work.

Summary:

1. Flash a fresh Raspbian install to your SD card, which will be used to boot the system.
2. Use fdisk to partition the SSD. Assuming the SSD is `/dev/sda`, run `fdisk /dev/sda`, `d`, `n`, enter for defaults, `w`, `q`.
3. Format the partition: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1`
4. Mount the partition:

```
mkdir /media/newdrive
mount /dev/sda1 /media/newdrive
```

5. Copy the OS: `rsync -avc / /media/newdrive`
6. Edit `/boot/cmdline.txt`, modify root device.

```
nano /boot/cmdline.txt
root=/dev/sda1 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
```

7. Reboot

Now you have a normal Raspbian install, without the berryboot limitations. Docker works fine with the overlay2 storage driver.